# The total sum of the terms of a sequence defined iteratively.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider the sequence of vectors defined as follows:

$v_{1} = (1)$, $v_{2} = (2)$, $v_{3} =(2,3)$ and for $i \geq 4$, let $v_{i-1} = (x_{1},\ldots,x_{p})$, then

$$ v_{i} = (2,3,4\ldots, x_{1}+1, 2,3,\ldots,x_{2},2,3\ldots x_{3}+1, \ldots, x_{p}+1)$$

In other words, $v_{i}$ is the concatenation of the vectors $(2,\ldots,x_{1}+1),\ldots,(2,\ldots,x_{p}+1)$. We have $v_{4} = (2,3,2,3,4)$, for example.

Let $S_{m}$ denote the sum of coordinates of $v_{m}$ for $m \geq 1$.

I need to show that  $S_{m} = \frac{1}{m+1} {2m \choose m}$. First I observed that the number of coordinates of $v_{m}$ is $S_{m-1}$. I tried to found recurrences that hold for both, $S_{m}$ and $\frac{1}{m+1} {2m \choose m}$ however I didn't find it. This problem appeared when I was trying to count some structures, then maybe my question is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the dots mean? How far do we go in each step?

Comment: @Phicar, It starts at 2 and increasing one by one when we achieve $x_{1}+1$, it starts again at $2$ and again increases one by one until $x_{2}+1$. We do it until arrive at $x_{p} + 1$.  I gave $v_{4} = (2,3,2,3,4)$ as example. Then to obtain $v_{5}$ we have $x_{1} = 2, x_{2}=3, x_{3} = 2,x_{4} = 3, x_{5} = 4$. Then $v_{5} = (2,3 = x_{1}+1,2,3,4=x_{2} + 1, 2,3=x_{3} + 1, 2,3,4 = x_{4} + 1,2,3,4,5=x_{5} + 1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So consider the following numbers
$$A_{n,k}=\text{# of times k is in }v_n.$$ First notice that the maximum element in $v_n$ is $n$ (induction i guess) and denote $l_n$ the length of $v_n,$ then we have first that $$l_n=\sum _{k=2}^nT_{n,k}$$ and also that
$$S_n=\sum _{k=2}^nk\cdot T_{n,k}.$$
As you have notice and is easy to show by construction $l_n=S_{n-1}.$ So we will focus just in the sum. 
Notice also that $$A_{n,k}=\sum _{j=k-1}^{n-1}A_{n-1,j}$$ because in your construction you will go from $2$ to $j+1$ and so every time we see a number greater than $k-1$ we should pass by $k$ in the next generation. Consider now the change of variable $T_{n,k}=A_{n,n-k+1}$ this will allow you to have the recursion
$$T_{n,k}=\sum _{j=1}^{k-1}T_{n-1,j}$$ then a table of this numbers looks like

> 1 [1](https://oeis.org/A009766)
> 2 [1, 1]
> 3 [1, 2, 2]
> 4 [1, 3, 5, 5]
> 5 [1, 4, 9, 14, 14]
> 6 [1, 5, 14, 28, 42, 42]
> 7 [1, 6, 20, 48, 90, 132, 132]
> 8 [1, 7, 27, 75, 165, 297, 429, 429]

I generate this table using your construction:

```
L =[2]
for k in range(1,8):
        LL=[]
        for n in range(0,len(L)):
                for m in range(2,L[n]+2):
                        LL.append(m)
        LLL = [0]*(k+1)
        for i in range(0,len(LL)):
                LLL[k+2-LL[i]]+=1
        print(k+1,LLL)
        L = LL
```

It turns out that this numbers are in the [OEIS A009766](https://oeis.org/A009766).
There you will see that they are counting some structures with particular properties, and when you add this structures you get a structure counted by Catalan numbers.